# Elastic Search 403 error

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda

Elastic search responding with 403 error when the user requesting for a markup search.The error is given below.

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://search-elastic-search-stage-skjfdfsd.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/markup_retailer/_search
```

Can  anyone guide me resolve the issue.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP-403 is the unauthorized response code...
Can you test with curl
curl -u youruser:yourpassword -XPOST https://search-elastic-search-stage-skjfdfsd.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/markup_retailer/_search -d '{copy your request body here}' ?
You will probably see the response body of elasticsearch is much more precise saying which privilege the user is missing